# How to make a Fork or a Join cross two Swinlanes of Activity Diagram in IBM RSA?

Tags: diagram, rational-rsa

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. 
Just tried a little more times, and I found if I drag the bar directly on the middle line, it crosses the line automatically.